# Drop Master Key keeps on running

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

I am trying to drop master key of the database, but everytime I run the below sql

```
DROP MASTER KEY
```

The query keeps on executing and never completes.

Answer (score 2):

Whenever I issue a command that should finish instantaneously but doesn't, blocking comes to mind. So I'll note the SPID of the window where I issued the command and then `select * from sys.dm_os_waiting_tasks where session_id = @spid` and resolve whatever the block is.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have "Control" permissions on the database? If so, are there any private keys in the database? Have they been removed prior to performing this operation?

Comment: I do have control permissions on the db and there are no keys in the db at the time when I try to drop master key. I checked the keys existance using the sqls select * from sys.symmetric_keys and 
select * from sys.asymmetric_keys

Comment: Put this through the query profiler and see whats going on. That would be your best bet I guess.

Comment: From profiler I can see lock acquired for symmetric_key_id = 101

Comment: Find the transaction that has acquired the lock on this. If this is your production server, I advise you consult with your team before killing off the process. Once you kill off the process, you should be able to easily run the query. Let us know if you successfully kill of the transaction and run the query.

Comment: Well I can see multiple Lock: Acuired and Lock: Released staments from my own spid. Can't see anything else which is suspisuous.

Comment: And this not a server, its a dev machine.

Answer (score 0):

I could repeat that only by 2 query windows. In one:

```
create  master key ENCRYPTION BY PASSWORD = 'password'
begin tran --!!!
OPEN MASTER KEY DECRYPTION BY PASSWORD = 'password'
```

The second window:

```
drop master key -- waits...
```

So maybe someone is using that master key!
You should probably kick all other users from db and try then.. Or find out who is using it (yourself?).

Comment: So I tried after restarting sql server. Stil the same result :(

Answer (score 0):

So I got it working after disabling Service Broker.